# Arcsine transformation of percentage data

Tags: r

**I need to arcsine transform my data, but as I've never done this before I'm not sure if the code I'm using is right, and therefore I don't know how to address errors when they occur.**

[image: (csv) HS.PvsPERC]

My code (using csv: HS.PvsPERC):

```
mydata<-read.csv(file.choose())

attach(mydata)
summary(mydata)
str(mydata)
head(mydata)
dput(mydata)

mydata <-
structure(list(Herd.size = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Large", "Small"), class = "factor"), 
    Any.pregnant.in.herd. = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no clear evidence", 
    "pregnant"), class = "factor"), percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway = c(0, 
    100, 80, 25, 57.14, 100, 0, 25, 50, 100, 100, 70, 100, 14.29, 
    26.67, 100, 50, 40, 67.65, 43.59, 5.41, 44.9, 41.5, 69.23, 
    14.29, 7.07, 6.05)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))

shapiro.test(mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway)
length(percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway)

mydatatrans<-asin(sqrt(mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway))
```

The last line produces the error:

> **Warning message:
>   In asin(sqrt(mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway)) : NaNs produced**

which I am unsure in how to change/ interpret.

---

I also tried (as suggested help in other answers):

```
trans.arcsine<-asin(sign(mydata)*sqrt(abs(mydata)))
```

> **Error in Math.data.frame(mydata) : 
>     non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: Herd.size, Any.pregnant.in.herd.**

(for any pregnant in herd column, I have used pregnant and no clear evidence- should I make them numeric, as 1 and 0s or something similar?)

```
trans.arcsine<-function(mydata){asin(sign(mydata)*sqrt(abs(mydata)))}
trans.arcsine(Herd.size~Any.pregnant.in.herd.)
```

> **Error in sign(mydata) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function**

**I'm trying to compare herd size and pregnancy with percentage of heads up- which is supposed to be a 2 way anova, but need to transform the data first.**

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mydata)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mydata, 20))`.

Comment: I hope that helps, if not I have also included a picture @RuiBarradas

Comment: Yes, it does help. Also, why the square root? is it part of a formula you are trying to apply?

Comment: My lecturer told me to add that during a help session, will it make more sense without? @RuiBarradas

Comment: I really cannot tell, that is a question for your lecturer. Anyway, the function should be easy to adapt, just remove `sqrt` from the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your column ranges from 0 to 100, and the arcsin can only be applied to numbers from 0 to 1.  I'm assuming that these percentages should be scaled from 0 to 1 by dividing by 100, and then take the square root of the rescaled number.

```
mydatatrans <- asin(sqrt(mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway / 100))
```

Results for the `mydata` in question:

```
> mydatatrans
 [1] 0.0000000 1.5707963 1.1071487 0.5235988 0.8570431 1.5707963 0.0000000 0.5235988
 [9] 0.7853982 1.5707963 1.5707963 0.9911566 1.5707963 0.3876579 0.5426768 1.5707963
[17] 0.7853982 0.6847192 0.9657860 0.7211213 0.2347441 0.7343093 0.6999833 0.9827854
[25] 0.3876579 0.2691319 0.2485177
```

Edit:

Changed the data frame name from `df` to `mydata`.

Comment: asin(sqrt(df$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway/100))                                           Error in df$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable @R. Schifini

Comment: @BethCarpenter This is because the answer code is using `df` and not `mydata` as the dataframe name. Just change that and it works.

Comment: so its supposed to look like: asin(sqrt(mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway/100))
numeric(0) Could you please explain a bit further what this actually means? @RuiBarradas

Comment: @BethCarpenter I am not geting `numeric(0)`, you must be doing something else that makes of `mydata$percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway` a vector of length zero.

Comment: the numeric(0) output has now gone, data now shows as above, thank you, so do I now use these numbers as my new data?

Comment: To add a new column do: `mydata$new_column = mydatatrans`, where `new_column` could be any name you want that is not a column in `mydata` or one of the already existing to overwrite that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984490/arcsine-transformation-of-percentage-data/55985202#55985202) of user R. Schifini more general by defining a function to take care of the scaling for you and then compute the arcsin.

```
arcsin <- function(x, col = 3){
  scaled <- x[[col]]/diff(range(x[[col]]))
  asin(sqrt(scaled))
}

arcsin(mydata)
arcsin(mydata, 'percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway')
```

Notes:

- `col = 3` is the default input column.
- If you pass a column name in argument `col`, it must be a character string, meaning, it must be quoted like in the second usage example.
- The scaling uses `diff` and therefore does not depend on the particular range of the input vector.

Comment: so the output values: arcsin(mydata, 'percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway')
 [1] 0.0000000 1.5707963 1.1071487 0.5235988 0.8570431 1.5707963 0.0000000 0.5235988 0.7853982
[10] 1.5707963 1.5707963 0.9911566 1.5707963 0.3876579 0.5426768 1.5707963 0.7853982 0.6847192
[19] 0.9657860 0.7211213 0.2347441 0.7343093 0.6999833 0.9827854 0.3876579 0.2691319 0.2485177                     Can I run a 2 way anova on those? @RuiBarradas

Comment: @BethCarpenter You will need factor columns.

Comment: How do I create factor columns?

Comment: herd1<-factor(c("Small", "Large"), ordered = TRUE)
preg1<-factor(c("pregnant", "no clear evidence"), ordered = TRUE)

Comment: @BethCarpenter Any of `fit <- lm(percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway ~ percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway ~ Herd.size*Any.pregnant.in.herd., mydata);anova(fit)` or `model <- aov(percentage.of.heads.up.at.halfway ~ Herd.size*Any.pregnant.in.herd., mydata);summary(model)`.

Comment: As `diff(range(x))` could be smaller than the highest value (i.e. max(x)), `x/diff(range(x))` could be bigger than `1` and `asin` will return `NaN`. Maybe replace `diff(range(x))` by `max(x)`, but I will keep on the standard `asin(sqrt(x))`, 0<= x <= 1.